# Why does O2 gets less compressed as compared to CH4 when pressure is applied?

Tags: gas-laws, ideal-gas

As I understand it, the compression depends on the attractive forces between the molecules. And considering that both $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{CH4}$ do not have any dipole-dipole interaction with their respective molecules, The attractive forces should just be van der waals forces, that depend on mass and surface area of contact between the molecules only. As $\ce{O2}$ has more mass and more surface area of contact than $\ce{CH4}$ (as $\ce{CH4}$ is spherical in shape), it should be compressed more.

[image: this is the graph provided in my text book]

Comment: Do you know what shape each of those molecules are? Geometry means one type fits nicely together compared to the other, so less force is required to make it do so. CH4 is far from being spherical.

Comment: But so are diatomic molecules.